# Why does $scope in angular logs as 'b' and its parent as 'm'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This might be more of a theoretical question, but I noticed that in my AngularJS app (v. 1.5.7), when console.log($scope) is done in a controller, it prints as an object with a label 'b'.

It's 'parent' prints with a value 'm'.

Is there some reason for this? Any significance to this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Minification would be my guess. Try using an un-minified version of `angular.js` and see what it says

Comment: *"Any significance to this"* ...Not really for you as  developer...chalk it up to angular internals or possibly even browser console. If you need parent for example you simply use `$scope.$parent`

Comment: @Phil, yep, that's what it was. In the un-minified version, it displays "ChildScope" and "Scope" for $rootScope. So, it's just a named object. Thanks!